# KQL language reference for Search Result Sources

Tags: 2013, search-results, keyword-query-language

I'm just getting into KQL and using the query builder with custom search result sources in my site collection. I've found [this documentation on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and that is very helpful, but I don't think it is complete.

I'm seeing things in the default queries and on tutorial sites like:

```
contentclass:sts_listitme OR IsDocument:True
```

or

```
spcontenttype:document author:mikael
```

I'm guessing those are property queries, but I'm not finding much documentation on them especially with regards to SP 2013. I know that the properties available will change with different installations and custimizations. But I'm wondering if there is a list of them based on the default SP features? Things like IsDocument and contentclass aren't anything I set up. And where would I find the difference between IsDocument:True and spcontenttype:document?

Does anybody have a good reference for these? Or a way to discover the possible properties and values?

Answer (score 1):

The complete list of properties is based on the Search Service Application, Site Collection and Site. You can get the list available to you through the Search Schema setting and observe the Managed Properties.

Comment: Thank you. That looks really helpful. Looks like our site/farm has 2197 of them. So I've got a lot of looking to do!

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to do, but, YES, it can be a daunting task. Let me know what you are doing and I may be able to help.

Comment: Just trying to learn KQL. My first big question would be, what is the difference between IsDocument:True and spcontenttype:document?

Comment: IsDocument is not bound to ContentType.